# Toggle button : Hide counter numbers with background Color

Tags: javascript

Onclick button, I want to hide the numbers of this counter with background-color i.e.yellow). For example I want the yellow color in front of numbers, something like z-index 1.

If I click again I want to remove yellow color and show me the numbers of the counter again, something like z-index -1. Is it possible?
I have tried this..  Thanks

```js
var countStep = 0;

function counter() {
  document.getElementById("btnToggle").innerHTML = ++countStep;
}

function btnColor(btn, color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(btn);
  if (property.className !== 'toggled') {
    property.style.backgroundColor = color;
    property.className = 'toggled'
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(244,113,33)";
    property.className = '';
  }
}
```

```css
#btnToggle {
  background: #222;
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<p id="btnToggle">OFF</p>
<button onClick="countNumbers = setInterval(counter, 1000)">Play</button>

<button onClick="clearInterval(countNumbers)">Stop</button>

<input type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Toggle" onclick="btnColor('btnToggle','rgb(255,242,0)');" />
```

Comment: You have two elements with the same ID... `<p id="btnToggle">OFF</p>` and  `<input type="button" id="btnToggle"...` Id attribute should be unique to only one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to use rule `z-index: -1` for the counter text relative to the tag `p`. It is necessary to wrap the counter in an additional `span` tag:

```
<p id="btnToggle"><span>OFF</span></p>
```

Using the `querySelector()`:

```
var countContent = document.querySelector("#btnToggle span");
```

Further, in the very logic of js, inside the `if { ... }` condition, it is necessary to assign a negative value `z-index`:

```
countContent.style.zIndex = '-1';
```

Else, disable (default):

```
countContent.style.zIndex = '';
```

And most importantly, the `span` tag must be set **absolute** and `#btnToggle` **relative**. Add this to your css:

```
#btnToggle span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also, your tag `p` and tag `input` have the same **id**. And this is incorrect, since the id is a unique attribute.

```js
var countStep = 0;
var countContent = document.querySelector("#btnToggle span");

function counter() {
    countContent.innerHTML = ++countStep;
}

function btnColor(btn, color) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.className !== "toggled") {
        property.style.backgroundColor = color;
        property.className = "toggled";
        countContent.style.zIndex = '-1';
    } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(244,113,33)";
        property.className = "";
        countContent.style.zIndex = '';
    }
}
```

```css
#btnToggle {
    background: #222;
    color: lime;
    position: relative;
    height: 18px;
}

#btnToggle span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p id="btnToggle"><span>OFF</span></p>
<button onClick="countNumbers = setInterval(counter, 1000)">Play</button>
<button onClick="clearInterval(countNumbers)">Stop</button>
<input type="button" id="btnToggle_two" value="Toggle" onclick="btnColor('btnToggle','rgb(255,242,0)');" />
```

Comment: `p` and the `input` both have the same `id` of `#btnToggle`.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal, thanks. I didn't notice it. I'll fix it now

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Yes, it will be hidden with the yellow color, but it can also be done with two layers and z-index command ?? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Alex, the bottom line is that your html structure does not have an element that can overlap the counter content using rule z-index. And even more so, your counter and background are the same element - p tag.

Comment: You're right @s.kuznetsov . So I correct my question. Can it be done with two elements and z-index?

Comment: I mean, can I use two elements and not one as I did, and with the z-index command, the yellow color appears in front of the numbers (z-index:1)?. 

And if I press the toggle button again, the yellow color will hide behind the numbers, and the numbers will appear again..  (z-index:-1). Is it possible with z-index command?

Comment: @Alex, Let me drive to my work and upon arrival, I will make a second decision for you if I have time.

Comment: @Alex, I completely redid the solution. Or rather, im made a new decision and deleted the previous one. Now works using `z-index: -1` and the counter text is completely hidden behind the yellow background.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's great @s.kuznetsov

Comment: @Alex, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

**First you will need to change the id of the p tag or inputs selector so they are *unique***. Then use the psuedo element for the p tag selector in CSS. Style its **position** to **absolute** and set **left**, **top**, **width** and **height** and `display: var(--display)` => the variable set from the root element. Then you can set the `:root` style with a css variable that affects the display of your p tags style `--display: none` to start.

Check the computed style `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#btnToggle'), ':before').getPropertyValue, ':before').getPropertyValue('display') === 'none'` in a conditional to see if it is set to `display:none`, if it is, then set the `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--display', 'block')` to display `block` ***else*** => `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--display', 'none')`

```js
let countStep = 0,
  btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  btnToggle = document.getElementById('btnToggle')

function counter() {
  document.getElementById("btnToggle").innerHTML = ++countStep;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#btnToggle'), ':before').getPropertyValue('display') === 'none' ? document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--display', 'block') :
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--display', 'none')
})
```

```css
:root {
  --display: none;
}

#btnToggle {
  background: #222;
  color: lime;
}

#btnToggle:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  content: '';
  width: 98vw;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: var(--display);
}
```

```html
<p id="btnToggle">OFF</p>
<button onClick="countNumbers = setInterval(counter, 1000)">Play</button>

<button onClick="clearInterval(countNumbers)">Stop</button>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Toggle" />
```

Comment: That's awesome!!! Is it possible to work with z-index command too?

Comment: Why do you want to affect z-index? And in what way do you want z-index to be affected?

Comment: There is no need to use z-index here, but in short yes you can get and set any css property using the css variable to set and computedStyle to get...